# Python 3.4 : Pandas DataFrame not responding to ordered dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I am populating a `DataFrame` with an ordered dictionary, but the `pandas DataFrame` is alphabetically organizing the columns.

## code

```
    labels = income_data[0:-1:4]

    year1 = income_data[1:-1:4]
    key = eachTicker
    value = OrderedDict(zip(labels, year1))
    full_dict[key] = value

    df = pd.DataFrame(full_dict)

print(df)
```

As you can see below `full_dict` is a zipped dictionary from multiple lists, namely : `labels` and `year1`

## output of `full_dict`

```
print(full_dict)
OrderedDict([('AAPL', OrderedDict([('Total Revenue', 182795000), ('Cost of Revenue', 112258000), ('Gross Profit', 70537000), ('Research Development', 6041000), ('Selling General and Administrative', 11993000), ('Non Recurring', 0), ('Others', 0), ('Total Operating Expenses', 0), ('Operating Income or Loss', 52503000), ('Total Other Income/Expenses Net', 980000), ('Earnings Before Interest And Taxes', 53483000), ('Interest Expense', 0), ('Income Before Tax', 53483000), ('Income Tax Expense', 13973000), ('Minority Interest', 0), ('Net Income From Continuing Ops', 39510000), ('Discontinued Operations', 0), ('Extraordinary Items', 0), ('Effect Of Accounting Changes', 0), ('Other Items', 0), ('Net Income', 39510000), ('Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments', 0), ('Net Income Applicable To Common Shares', 39510000)]))])
```

The outputted `DataFrame` is ordered alphabetically and I do not know why.  I want it to be ordered as in `full_dict`

## code output

```
                                           AAPL      AMZN     LNKD
Cost of Revenue                         112258000  62752000   293797
Discontinued Operations                         0         0        0
Earnings Before Interest And Taxes       53483000     99000    31205
Effect Of Accounting Changes                    0         0        0
Extraordinary Items                             0         0        0
Gross Profit                             70537000  26236000  1924970
Income Before Tax                        53483000   -111000    31205
Income Tax Expense                       13973000    167000    46525
Interest Expense                                0    210000        0
Minority Interest                               0         0     -427
Net Income                               39510000   -241000   -15747
Net Income Applicable To Common Shares   39510000   -241000   -15747
Net Income From Continuing Ops           39510000   -241000   -15747
Non Recurring                                   0         0        0
Operating Income or Loss                 52503000    178000    36135
Other Items                                     0         0        0
Others                                          0         0   236946
Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments           0         0        0
Research Development                      6041000         0   536184
Selling General and Administrative       11993000  26058000  1115705
Total Operating Expenses                        0         0        0
Total Other Income/Expenses Net            980000    -79000    -4930
Total Revenue                           182795000  88988000  2218767
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `DataFrame` ctor in that it's not respecting the key order when the orient is 'columns' a work around is to use [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) and transpose the result when you specify the orient as 'index':

```
In [31]:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
df

Out[31]:
                                             AAPL
Total Revenue                           182795000
Cost of Revenue                         112258000
Gross Profit                             70537000
Research Development                      6041000
Selling General and Administrative       11993000
Non Recurring                                   0
Others                                          0
Total Operating Expenses                        0
Operating Income or Loss                 52503000
Total Other Income/Expenses Net            980000
Earnings Before Interest And Taxes       53483000
Interest Expense                                0
Income Before Tax                        53483000
Income Tax Expense                       13973000
Minority Interest                               0
Net Income From Continuing Ops           39510000
Discontinued Operations                         0
Extraordinary Items                             0
Effect Of Accounting Changes                    0
Other Items                                     0
Net Income                               39510000
Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments           0
Net Income Applicable To Common Shares   39510000
```

**EDIT**

The bug is due to line 5746 in index.py:

```
def _union_indexes(indexes):
    if len(indexes) == 0:
        raise AssertionError('Must have at least 1 Index to union')
    if len(indexes) == 1:
        result = indexes[0]
        if isinstance(result, list):
            result = Index(sorted(result)) # <------ culprit
        return result
```

When it constructs the index, it extracts the key using `result = indexes[0]` but then it checks if it's a list and if so sorts the result: `result = Index(sorted(result))` this is why you get this result.

[Issue here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10514)

[duplicate issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8425)

Comment: @EdChum, you are very very knowledgable! And actually I used to just reorder based on keys afterward, great to know the truth now! +999

Comment: @EdChum it's weird but supposedly there was a problem with `DataFrames` responding to `OrderedDict` a while ago and it mentions in multiple places that it has been fixed.... obviously not

Comment: I'm currently trying to debug this, when you pass `orient='index'` it constructs a list of the dict key values which is why it works in that case, I'm trying to understand what's going on when you set `orient='columns'` which is the default

Comment: OK found the problem, the order is being blatted in `index.py` line 5746 by this line `result = Index(sorted(result))` so when you have nested dicts it's ignoring or not checking the fact that the original dtype was an `OrderedDict` which is why you get the sorted output